# Websphere administration tool application

Tags: java, websphere, administration

I'm trying to create a simple  admin client application for websphere:

my code:

> Properties connectProps = new Properties();
>   connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE,
>   AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);
>   connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED,
>   "true");
>
> connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, "XXXXX");
>   connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, "8879");
>   connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, "admin");
>   connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, "admin");
>   connectProps.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\Users\DummyClientTrustFile.jks");
>   connectProps.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",
>   "C:\Users\DummyClientKeyFile.jks");
>   connectProps.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "admin");
>   connectProps.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "admin");
>
> AdminClient adminClient = null; try {
>          adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(connectProps); } catch
>   (ConnectorException e) {
>          System.out.println("Exception creating admin client: " + e);
>
> ```
>  e.printStackTrace(); }
> ```
>
> }

the error message I receive:

> com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException:
>   ADMC0016E:The system cannot  create a SOAP connector to connect to
>   host xxxx at port 8879.
>           at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPriv
>   ileged(AdminClientFactory.java:635)
>           at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.access$000(AdminClien
>   tFactory.java:127)
>           at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory$1.run(AdminClientFact
>   ory.java:210)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessControll
>   er.java:63)
>           at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(Adm
>   inClientFactory.java:206)
>           at TryConnection1.main(TryConnection1.java:42) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>
> ```
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
> ```
>
> rce)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPriv
>   ileged(AdminClientFactory.java:457)
>           ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.WASinvoke(Ljava
>   /net/URL;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/soap/rpc/Response;
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$4.run(SOAPCo
>   nnectorClient.java:373)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessControll
>   er.java:118)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SO
>   APConnectorClient.java:366)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.(SOAPC
>   onnectorClient.java:222)
>           ... 10 more
>   ---- Begin backtrace for nested exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>
> ```
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
> ```
>
> rce)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPriv
>   ileged(AdminClientFactory.java:457)
>           at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.access$000(AdminClien
>   tFactory.java:127)
>           at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory$1.run(AdminClientFact
>   ory.java:210)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessControll
>   er.java:63)
>           at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(Adm
>   inClientFactory.java:206)
>           at TryConnection1.main(TryConnection1.java:42) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.WASinvoke(Ljava
>   /net/URL;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/soap/rpc/Response;
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$4.run(SOAPCo
>   nnectorClient.java:373)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessControll
>   er.java:118)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SO
>   APConnectorClient.java:366)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.(SOAPC
>   onnectorClient.java:222)
>           ... 10 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're mixing the wrong jars/jre's in your classpath. Probably IBM adminclient jars and sun JRE? Or wrong xml/soap jars?

I never actually tried to call the adminclient jars directly. A better supported way is to use IBM's wsadmin.sh script and call the AdminClient interface via jython. Behind the screens, this will also do what you did from java, so you could reverse engineer that script to see which jre and which jars are actually used to make the magic work.

See http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rxml_commandline.html for websphere v6.1 documentation on wsadmin.